# Tableau - extra column based om sums

Tags: tableau-api

I'm just starting to learn Tableau and I have a question. I have a quarter profits overview as shown in the picture. I like to add a new column based on a calculation rule from the sums in the table (see notes about column Q-dif in paint on the right). How can I add this extra column?

[image]

Data is simple overview of all orderlines:
Product x | categorie y | salesprice |

Thank you in advance,

Greetings J.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions. It wont create a column but it will still give you what you may be looking for.

1. Create a calculated field under "Analysis" and enter this:
   (ZN(SUM([Verkoopb..])) - LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([Verkoopb..])), -1)) /
   ABS(LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([Verkoopb..])), -1))
2. Drag newly created calculated field into mark pane
3. Right click pill and format numbers as %'s

OR get the same results by:

1. Bringing in a second Verkoopb.. pill under where your original
   Verkoopb.. pill is
2. Right click the second Verkoopb.. pill you just dropped and select
   Quick table calculation and select Percent Difference
3. Drag pill to the pane.

Hope this works.